# auto-expand related attribute on query

Tags: wakanda

I have seen on the [Wakanda Quickstart](https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-javascript-client/wiki/Quickstart#expanding) guide that you can autoexpand (fetch) a related attribute on client-side with the dataprovider:

```js
ds.Employee.find(4, {expand: 'employer'})
```

Is it possible to do this on the ***server-side***?

I have tried option `autoexpand` on dataStore query but it doesn't work.

Comment: As a side note, the page you linked is about `Wakanda-Client`, the new javascript client for Wakanda (it's still on beta). It's a completely different framework that the dataProvider.

Answer (score 3):

In the Server Side you don't need the expand option to retrieve the employer.
You can reach it directly :

```
var emp = ds.Employee.find('ID = 2');
var employer = emp.employer;
```

Comment: thanks Walid. I know that but I want to construct a single JSON that contains a hierarchy structure with all related attributes. I wondered if I could do it with one line of code or if I need to loop through each related attribute to construct my JSON.

Comment: you're welcome Laurent. With this way , you'll not need to loop through the related attributes, the data of the 'employer' is already available.